# asp.NET 5 MVC6 Bearer Token Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I need a website to validate its request to an API using a bearer token. Same token can be used for all requests as the site is public so no need for a user login.

I have been using a bit of a mashup from [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/master/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Providers/AuthorizationProvider.cs) and other SO questions.

API Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        //add functionality similar to [ClaimsAuthorize("myclaim")]
        .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name)
        .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
        .Build();

        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter(policy));                
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //Authorization
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:44380";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44380";
        });

        // Add a new middleware issuing tokens.
        app.UseOpenIdConnectServer
        (
            configuration =>
            {
                configuration.TokenEndpointPath = "/login";
                configuration.AllowInsecureHttp = false;
                configuration.Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider();
            }
        );
    }
```

AuthorizationServerProvider

```
    public override async Task GrantClientCredentials(GrantClientCredentialsContext context)
    {
        DbContext dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
        Client client = await dbContext.Clients.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == context.ClientId);

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, client.Name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientId));

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), 
            new AuthenticationProperties(),
            OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
```

Client Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //Used with TempData
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            // Note: these settings must match the application details
            // inserted in the database at the server level.
            options.ClientId = Configuration.Get<string>("Constants:ClientMvcId");
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.Get<string>("Constants:ClientMvcSecret");

            // Use the authorization code flow.
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.Code;
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Now when `OnAuthorizationAsync`in `AuthenticationFilter`is called, `AuthorizationContext.HttpContext.User.Claims` is empty so I can't check the values.

Comment: Could you please share your client-side code and a trace of a token request and an API request (with the authorization header)? Also, have you tried enabling logging?

Comment: I haven't tried adding logging. Is that the default logging in the Configure method in Startup.cs?

Comment: Yep. Take a look at the MVC sample to see how you can add console or debug logging.